# Em editor phone number formatting

Tags: emeditor

I have phone number/number look like this
xxxxxxxxxx
I want to turn it to this formatting on em editor xxx-xxx-xxxx
Basically 3 digit -3 digit -4 digit like an USA phone number.

How can I do it?

Formatting phone number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Replace. Find the Regular Expressions pattern `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})` and replace with `\1-\2-\3`. The pattern looks for a string of 10 digits and then uses backreferences to put dashes in between the digits.

[image]